# ¿Cómo ejecutras una vista de MySQL con Nestjs y TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, nestjs, typeorm

Cordial saludo.

Estoy trabajando en una API REST hecha con NestJS, TypeORM y MySQL. Necesito crear una ruta que me traiga lo que devuelve una vista que tengo en la base de datos. La vista es sencilla, pero no he logrado hacerla funcionar en NestJS. He intentado varias cosas, pero no obtengo resultados. ¿Dónde puedo encontrar información sobre esto?

Comment: Creo que esto te puede ayudar [View Entities](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/view-entities)